# How to install gtk themes under NixOS without hacky scripts?

Tags: nixos

I can't find a proper way of setting gtk themes under NixOS. My usual approach is lxappearance, but after installing some gtk-themes with nix lxappearance can't find them (as there is no /usr/share/themes, but the themes aren't under .local/share/themes). In the case of fonts I can just use the fonts.fonts option in configuration.nix, but there is no option for this in the case of icons and themes. The only thing I found so far is this old [config.nix](https://github.com/neatonk/nixos-conf/blob/master/configuration.nix) with some scripts, but it is a really hacky solution, which I would rather not use.

I am using bspwm as window manager. Also, I tried installing it with configuration.nix as well as nix-env -i.

Comment: What is hacky about it? I configure all my themes & icons in my configuration.nix, in this way: https://github.com/bennofs/etc-nixos/blob/master/conf/desktop.nix

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`home-manager`](https://github.com/nix-community/home-manager)'s [`gtk.theme`](https://rycee.gitlab.io/home-manager/options.html#opt-gtk.theme) might be a good alternative.

If you plan to install things into an user environment in a declarative way, `home-manager` is a very good tool to use.

Using it, you can easily install (and set) a GTK theme declaratively on your `home.nix`:

```hs
{ pkgs, ... }:
{
  gtk = {
    enable = true;
    theme = {
      name = "Materia-dark";
      package = pkgs.materia-theme;
    };
  };
}
```